# Difficulty with select clause in natural join format

Tags: sql, join, oracle10g

I'm using Oracle 10g to create the following tables:

- **Book** (bookid (*pk*), title, author, subject)
- **Borrower** (bid (*pk*), name)
- **Borrows** (bookid (*fk*), bid(*fk*), date_of_issue, date_of_return)

Now I want to retrieve the bid and names of borrowers who have borrowed one or more books on DBMS.
To accomplish this I've written this query:

```
SELECT bid,name
FROM Book NATURAL JOIN Borrows NATURAL JOIN Borrower
WHERE subject='DBMS';
```

This gives correct result as per the data I inserted into the tables.
But the unexpected happens when I omit 'bid' from the SELECT clause.
If I only want to show the names, the result is surprisingly different. 
Even the output relation shows names of some members who have never borrowed any book yet!!!

I tried writing the same query with Oracle inner join format, ANSI inner join format and the nested query format. All these are showing correct output.
But why on earth would this happen only to the natural join format on omitting a single column?

Please don't tell me to use other formats to write this query. I surely would. But I need to know what actually has gone wrong.

Comment: Can you provide create table and insert scripts. It doesn't have to be your actual data, just enough to reproduce the problem. You could also try running both the correct and incorrect versions using [`EXPLAIN PLAN`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm) to try and see where the difference lies?

Comment: You've tagged this `oracle10g`.  What is the full version of Oracle that you're using?  The SQL 99 syntax was new in 10g and there were a few bugs in the translation of SQL 99 syntax to traditional join syntax.  `natural join` is a very, very seldomly used construct as well so it would be one of the least tested.  It is entirely possible that you are encountering a bug particularly if you are using an old, unpatched version of the database rather than, say, 10.2.0.4.

Comment: To know more about the version I've written the following query: select * from v$version; And this gives : BANNER
Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Product
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
CORE 10.2.0.1.0 Production
TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production